# How i can get the current wiki page version inside my list workflow 2013

Tags: workflow, publishing-site, workflow2013, list-workflow

I am working on an office 365 sharepoint online project. and i have an enterprise wiki site collections. where each wiki page have a version number as follow:-

[image]

now i have defined a list workflow on the Pages library. and inside the list WF i want to get the value for the wiki page Version. now i find 2 fields inside the WF 2013:-

1. Version
2. UI Version

and inside the workflow i want to check if the wiki page version is greater than or equal to 3. so i tried the following:-
[image]

but seems the UI Version field will have values such as `2102` or  `5123` and does not represent the actual page version. now i tried to use the Version field instead of UI Version field. but seems the Version will be a string so i can not check if it is greater than or equal to 3. so can anyone adivce on this please? how i can check if the wiki page version is `>= 3` inside my WF 2013 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every major version will in `UIVersion` be based on `version * 512`, so you will have to compare on `1536`.

### For completeness

Minor versions will increment the version with 1, and every major with `512`. So

- 0.1 is `1`
- 1.0 is `512`
- 1.1 is `513`
- 2.0 is `1024`
- 2.1 is `1025`

  and so on